# Problem installing NVIDIA Driver on 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have spent a lot of time troubleshooting this and finally need help.

Intel Core i5 6600K
16gb RAM
ASUS NVIDIA 1050ti OC GPU

My safeboot is disabled, and I have a DVI-D cable connecting my GPU to my monitor.

I used this website to install the latest NVIDIA driver for my GPU, nvidia-384-- http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux

The driver appears in my software folder. Upon reboot, I am brought to the login screen which is stretched and appears fuzzy. I cannot type anything to unlock the disk and am forced to press the reset switch on my PC. I am then brought to the GRUB menu where I manually uninstall the driver. Upon rebooting again, I can login no problem.

I have tried installing straight from the NVIDIA website after switching to the right X file mode and setting noveau=0. I have been uninstalling the drivers upon each attempt.

Can anyone help me on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First try the Nvidia drivers supplied by the normal repositories.

If those don't work, try one at a time, in oder a ppa graphics repository:
 graphics-drivers, x-swat, xorg-edgers
   e.g.:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

See

```
   https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
   https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/ubuntu/updates
   https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
```

Last resort would be the Nvidia site, possibly for the newest hardware.

Preparation

1)In your UEFI Settings (or BIOS):
  a) check for any video hardware selection.
     Choose "discrete" over "integrated" or "hybrid".
  b) Turn off secure boot, to avoid problems with unsigned
     kernel modules (post 14.04).

Nvidia drivers will need a recompile, but the default install will have all the necessary parts.

Ensure you are up-to-date with the default repositories:
In a terminal, type

```
sudo apt-get update
```

or

```
update-manager
```

From Dash, select "Software Updater" (start typing the name, and the selections will be available).

Now from Dash run

```
Software & Updates
```

or from a terminal type

```
update-manager
```

or from the "Software Updater", click on the Settings button at the lower left corner.

Under the "Ubuntu Software" tab:
ensure the "Proprietary drivers for devices (restricted)" is checked (It is by default).

Select the "Additional Drivers" tab
Select the latest Nvidia driver which is "(proprietary, tested)" (probably the first one listed) and click on the "apply changes" button.

The driver setup takes several minutes, but it does have a progress bar.

After the changes have been applied, the Nvidia button selected will be the active one.
Login again to restart X, and you should be running the Nvidia driver.  From Dash run

`Nvidia Settings`

to confirm.

---

No drivers at all in additional tabs...  Take a look at your UEFI settings (formerly known as BIOS) and see if you can select which video hardware is active.  Select "discrete" as opposed to "intergrated" or "hybrid".   Try running

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

to see the standard repository versions.  Take a look at other 1050ti postings here and in the forum like https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2353796  (Note OldFred's reply to the original post, cautioning against using the ...run method of installation.).

Comment: Thank you for all of this information! However, no (proprietary, tested) driver shows up on my additional drivers tab :( I have done every step you outlined!

Comment: In my case the proprietary driver appears but after I selected it and pushed 'Apply' the selection becomes again X.Org X server. Do you have any suggestions? I have been trying to solve the NVIDIA-CUDA issue for months...

Comment: Better to ask your own question with details like hardware, and errors. Generally, install the Nvidia drivers first, get them working, then do the CUDA install without its Nvidia drivers.  Your issue is probably leftover config files -- check the /etc/modprobe.d files for anything blacklisting nvidia *except nvidiafb, that's OK to blacklist).